# Troubleshooting Room Database: Cannot Find Implementation for AppDatabase_Impl

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to set up a Room database in my Android app, but I am getting the following error: "Cannot find implementation for com.example.myapp.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist". I have tried multiple solutions, including cleaning and rebuilding the project, adding kapt { generateStubs = true } and sourceSets { main { java { exclude '**/AppDatabase_Impl.java' } } } to my build.gradle file, and trying a different version of the Room library, but none of them have worked.

Steps tried as suggested by various previous answers, but none helped:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Adding kapt { generateStubs = true } and sourceSets { main { java { exclude '**/AppDatabase_Impl.java' } } } to the build.gradle file
- Trying a different version of the Room library
- Verifying that the @Database annotation is set up correctly
- Checking that the DAO is implemented correctly
- Making sure that the Room components are included in the dependencies
- Creating a new project and adding the Room components again
- Making sure that the annotation processor is included as a dependency
- Checking that there are no errors in the code (syntax, etc.)
- Trying to run the app on a different device or emulator
- Checking that the correct class name is being used in the Room.databaseBuilder() method

Here is my AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = [ChatRoom::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun chatRoomDao(): ChatRoomDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase{
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE

            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "user_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Dao
interface ChatRoomDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun createChatRoom(chatRoom: ChatRoom)

    @Query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS chat_room")
    fun dropChatRoom()
   
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertChatRoom(chatRoom: ChatRoom): Boolean

}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "chat_room")
data class ChatRoom(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_receiver") val receiver: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_sender") val sender: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_last_message") val lastMessage: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_last_message_time") val lastMessageTime: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_last_message_status") val lastMessageStatus: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_sender_profile") val senderProfile: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_sender_name") val senderName: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_receive_name") val receiverName: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_receiver_profile") val receiverProfile: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_unread") val unread: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_room_last_type") val lastType: String? = null
)
```

My library

```
// Room components
    def room_version = "2.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

My plugins

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android'
```

Comment: @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
Do you need to provide default value to primary key?

Comment: I correct that, but the main issue still there app crashing,  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.net.abstract.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

Comment: @osasdivine hi! Did you find any solution? =)